# return minified partial view from action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minify, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am currently building an ASP.Net Core 3 MVC application. It is a pretty simple Task, I want to return a partial view, but minified in order to save bandwidth.

My current code looks something like the following:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Page()
{
    ...

    return PartialView("_PartialView1", object);
}
```

I mean yea, I could just replace any kind of `\n\r`, Tabs and spaces, but for the spaces it would also remove spaces which are actually needed.

Comment: Why not have your web server use gzip compression?

Comment: Well yes, I have br compression as well, but compressing dynamically generated content over SSL is a bad idea, since it opens up a vulnerability right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there we are about a month later, since I haven't found any good solution which fits my needs, I went ahead and created a Visual Studio Extension which automatically minfies `.cshtml` files on save.

So if you are in the same situation as me, give [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=twenty-four-minutes.razor-minifier) a shot. The source-code for the extension is available over on [GitHub](https://github.com/TwentyFourMinutes/RazorMinifier).